# Zend Framework 2 forms, did they eliminated the decorator pattern?

Tags: php, zend-form, zend-framework2

I'm currently learning ZF2, is it possible that the Form decorator pattern from ZF1 has been removed in ZF2?

Am I right writing own view helper instead, decorating my forms?

Comment: Yep, ViewHelpers replaced the whole decorator (pattern|bullsh*t) - MUCH easier to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorators in ZF2 no longer exist. They were a mess in ZF1 even. However feel free to make your own decorators. You might also be interested in checking out Form Collections http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.collections.html

Comment: Thanks @Diemuzi. ZF2: are there ready-to-go third-party decorators for Zend\Form?

Comment: I actually have not seen any since ZF2 began but when in doubt, you can always try checking out http://modules.zendframework.com/